# How to change default “please include an @ in the email address”?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I am trying to change the default error message *"setCustomValidity"* throws on email being invalid.**

*I cannot access the source code.* My assumption is that the source somehow invokes *setCustomValidity*; just because of the look of the error message. This is the source element:

```
<input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="email" class="large" size="30">
```

***I can only inject any change using external JavaScript/css file.***

I could think of two solutions.

**Solution 1:** I am trying to inject inline HTML element using JS which would result in something like this.

```
<input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" class="large" size="30" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid email')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
```

I am new to JS and I am having a hard time figuring how to implement HTML in an external JS file.

**Solution 2:** Invoke the *oninvalid* and *setCustomValidity* DOM methods in `error_message.js` like so:

```
function emailValidity(){
    var myInput = document.getElementByName("customer[email]");
    myInput.oninvalid = function() { 
                (errorMessage) 
            };
    function errorMessage(){
        myInput.setCustomValidity("hey! the email isn't right");
    }
    }
```

But this file even after being included somehow fails to override the default message!

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Additionally you must call the reportValidity method on the same element or nothing will happen.

[HTMLObjectElement.setCustomValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity)

```js
function validate(input) {

  var validityState_object = input.validity;

  console.log(validityState_object)

  if (validityState_object.typeMismatch) {
    input.setCustomValidity('Thats not an email!');
    input.reportValidity();
  } else {
    input.setCustomValidity('');
    input.reportValidity();
  }
}

document.querySelector('#email').addEventListener('blur', e =>
  validate(e.target)
)
```

```html
<input type="email" value="" id="email">
```

Comment: Nice solution using only javascript! I missed the part with injection only, but yours works like a knife through butter. However, a form solution still might work, since an input type of email probably is wrapped in a form (at least that would be the logical thing to do).

Comment: Thank you @ksav. This solution worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `input` and `invalid` event listeners in much the same way.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.oninput = () => input.setCustomValidity('');
input.oninvalid = () => input.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid email');
```

```html
<form>
<input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" class="large" size="30">
</form>
```

Comment: You need to add a submit button for this to work.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon Pressing enter in the input field will submit the form.

Comment: @iota DOM functions are not recognized for some reason, if they are not put in a function while passing them through an external file. I will need to do more research on why the software I use behaves this way. I will let you know how that goes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code wasn't working because it wasn't in a form. A form needs a submit button to check the inputs and display an error message if necessary, so I added that.

Also, you have `getElementByName` when it should be `getElementsByName`, with a later on `[0]` indexing to select the element.

In addition to that, you were trying to set the validity every time the user tried to submit, when it only needed to be set once.

Try this:

```js
var myInput = document.getElementsByName("customer[email]")[0];
myInput.oninvalid = function() {
  myInput.setCustomValidity("Hey! the email isn't right")
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" name="customer[email]" id="email" class="large" size="30">
  <input type="submit" onsubmit="emailValidity()">
</form>
```

Comment: the input field is within a form along with a submit button. I did not mention it here thinking it was a given and also because click of enter works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

customAnswer.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // Source text: "Fill out this field."
  var validateElements1 = document.querySelectorAll('input#username, input#password');

  if (validateElements1.length > 0) {    
    for (var x = 0; x < validateElements1.length; x++) {
      validateElements1[x].setAttribute("oninvalid","this.setCustomValidity('Complete este campo.')");
      validateElements1[x].setAttribute("oninput","this.setCustomValidity('')");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).